# using fread() to read into a char * buffer

Tags: c++, pointers, char, buffer, fread

I've been working on a compression program for text files that uses a trie and custom bitstrings for each character. The file I'm reading from was written using `fwrite(name, wb)`, and I have looked over the file (in binary mode) and I have verified that the bits are correct to what they should have been written. The problem I am having is reading this binary file back into a file that can be read.

```
void read2(string fname, ofstream &outf)
{
    fname += ".mcp";
    outf << endl;
    std::ifstream inf(fname, std::ios::binary);
    std::vector<char> data{
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(inf),
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>() };
    std::cout << "Size: " << data.size() << '\n';
    std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(outf));
}
```

The output for this function (cout) is as follows:

```
Size: 25
```

(using a smaller test file)

The ofstream output should read:
    10001110 00000100 01001001 10110001 10011001 00101011 01101000 10010101 01000101 01010001
    01111010 01101001 10100110 01000000 01111010 00010111 00000110 10101000 11100000 01000101
    11011100 11110011 10010111 10001011 00000000
This is the binary form of the numbers that were read: (sorry its reading it as hex code, I copied it straight from the output file)

```
c5 bd 04 49 c2 b1 e2 84 a2 2b 68 e2 80 a2 45 51 7a 69 c2 a6 40 7a 17 06 c2 a8 c3 a0 45 c3 9c c3
b3 e2 80 94 e2 80 b9 20
```

I used the hex editor plugin for notepad++ to view the bits.

Comment: Does the binary data contain any NULs or SUBs (^@ or ^Z)?  Those might stop `cout <<` from processing any more characters.

Comment: `outf<<buffer;//writes the buffer to output file` no, this writes the c-string pointed to by `buffer` to the file, it will stop as soon as it hits a null character. A quick fix is to use `outf.write()` instead.

Comment: ^i will try that. and not that I know of, will see what i can do.

Comment: Edit:
i tried to use outf.write(buffer,lSize), I got a longer stream, but after the third byte, the data starts going wacky again. 
11100001 is the byte that should be read next but instead, when output it is 11000011 and after that everything else is completely wrong.

Comment: Use a working hex editor to make sure the file contains what you intend.  Then report what you read compared with what was in the file.  Is outf opened in binary mode?

Comment: Frankly, i'd lose the C-file stream entirely and just do [something like this](http://pastebin.com/r4vPLNkM).

Comment: @jdlugosz Im using notepad++ with the hex editor in binary mode to read it. Like i said, the first 3 bytes are what they should be, but everything after is garbage

Comment: @WhozCraig thank you! i will look into doing that!

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work @WhozCraig still just getting errors. The file that its reading from is correct and I have double checked that. So I'm not sure why Its reading the way it it.

Comment: @eragon2262  so tell us the three bytes plus a few more good and bad.  Report (to us) what you read, not re-state what you already did.

Comment: @eragon2262 to be frank I simply don't believe it. that code will read any file permissions allow, storing the data in a vector of unsigned char and making it available to do whatever you want. If your code still has `output << result;` it is just as wrong now as it was yesterday. Without more info including a **valid** [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including **exactly** what you're expecting, what you're getting, and sample data that shows evidence of all of the above there is little more anyone can do besides toss WAGs (wild-ass-guesses)

Comment: 10001110 00000100 01001001 10110001 10011001 00101011 01101000 10010101 01000101 01010001 01111010 01101001 10100110 01000000 01111010 00010111 00000110 10101000 11100000 01000101 11011100 11110011 10010111 10001011 00000000
Is what it should read, and what was output exactly like that.

This is the binary form of the numbers read: (sorry its reading it as hex code, I copied it straight from the output file)
c5 bd 04 49 c2 b1 e2 84 a2 2b 68 e2 80 a2 45 51 7a 69 c2 a6 40 7a 17 06 c2 a8 c3 a0 45 c3 9c c3 b3 e2 80 94 e2 80 b9 20

Comment: @WhozCraig I edited the post showing exactly the code in the function that I ran, as well as the output. I only had one that was already formatted from my program thats the binary. The hex was copied straight from the output file.

Comment: I *have* to ask. What on heavens earth does the binary representation of *any* of this have to do with slurping raw bytes out of a file into a container, doing something with them, then writing those bytes back out to a different file. And the `unsigned char`for the vector element type was no accident. If the actual **octets** were stored correct a `hexdump` of the source file being read by this program will be the *exact* content byte-for-byte that is in the `std::vector<>` (assuming you back out the change from `char` back to `unsigned char`).

Comment: And.. as was asked almost 24 hours by jdlugosz, "Is outf opened in binary mode" remains unanswered.

Comment: I am *attempting* to decompress a binary file I wrote using a compression algorithm that uses a Trie to create unique "bitstrings" for each character in the file, then write them in binary to compress the file. so I'm trying to read in the bytes that I wrote, so i can go through them to reconstruct the original text file. I am currently only outputting them to a file in binary so I can make sure its being read in correctly, hence the issue. I forgot I switched that, because the output is the same either way, I was just messing around with the code trying to see if I could tweak it.

Comment: I wish I had seen that part of his response earlier, I didn't realize it would matter since it was being read into a char buffer.I just created a new ofstream file and it worked. Thank you @WhozCraig
Sorry I dragged this on for so long.

Comment: and @jdlugosz thanks for pointing that out, wish I had noticed that part before it would have saved me a lot of trouble.

Comment: [**This paste**](http://pastebin.com/vz2bs1r4) has the *exact* code I linked near the top of this comment section, along with a test file that contains the *exact* bytes from your comment. both the original .mcp file and the resulting output file as *identical*, and is demonstrated via `hexdump`. My *only* point in this code is that it is trivial to load a vector of binary data from any file you have read permissions, and the link so-demonstrates that. Using formatted output to a binary-mode out stream is likely not going to work how you want (the modified `outf << endl` you added), btw.

Comment: I'm confused.   The hex is the view of the file you read, and the binary the output? They don't match at all, in count or values from the beginning.  I agree that using text output helps simplify the problem in that you are just worring about the read side.  Did you say you figured it out?  How about summarizing in a self answer for helping future searchers?

Comment: @jdlugosz the Binary was data that I was reading from, I had it output in readable text in an output file so I could compare it, which is why it doesn't change into hex. The Hex numbers are what I copied from notepad++ using a hex editor (http://prntscr.com/4vu0rk) thats how it looks in notepad++, but copying it on here automatically changed it to hex.

Comment: @eragon2262  but “10001110 00000100 01001001” is 8E 04 45 in hex, not at all resembling c5 bd 04.  By “they don't match” I am considering the difference in representation and comparing the bytes so-represented.

Comment: @jdlugosz Yes that's the point, I was trying to figure out why it doesn't match. If you convert the hex I gave you using a hex editor, it should be exactly the same as the binary.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on a good function for me to look into to compare the buffer bit by bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the question was actually very simple, the ofstream object, outf that I was using to output data to was not opened in binary mode, so I just created a new object in binary mode and output to it and it worked.

```
void read2(string fname, ofstream &outf)
{
    string fname1 =fname+ ".mcp", outfile="binarycheck";
    std::ifstream inf(fname1, std::ios::binary);
    std::ofstream ouf("binarycheck.txt", std::ios::binary);
    std::vector<unsigned char> data{
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(inf),
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>() };
    std::cout << "Size: " << data.size() << '\n';
    std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(ouf));
}
```